# get HTML between two PHP functions

Tags: php, templates

```
<html> 
<body>

<?php startblock("content"); ?>

<p> Page content </p>

<?php endblock("content"); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the content between the two php functions. If you look at the above example I want to get "`<p> page content <p>`" in a string.

Thanx in advance

Comment: <?php echo "<p> Page content </p>"; ?> ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Output Buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

```
<html> 
<body>

<?php ob_start(); ?>

<p> Page content </p>

<?php $html = ob_get_clean(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the functions like this:

```
function startblock()
{
  ob_start();
}

function endblock()
{
  $content = ob_get_flush();
  return '+++' . $content . '+++';
}
```

Note that you cannot nest this. As far as I know, you cannot have multiple output buffers that have a name. Therefor, the parameter you added has no use.

Comment: You can nest output buffering.
But you can not specify an ID to certain level.

Comment: two functions with same name?

Comment: Whoops. The second should have been 'endblock'.